# Can't parse haproxy logs without IP address in Grok using Filebeat

Tags: logging, logstash, haproxy, logstash-grok, filebeat

Grok is parsing successfully when Haproxy gives a log - from `var/log/haproxy.log` - similar to:

```
May 21 08:25:56 ha haproxy[5089]: 12.3.45.67:89012 [21/May/2021:08:25:56.055] www-https~ wss/wssnode website.domain.com 1/1/1/1/111 111 111 - - ---- 11111/11111/11111/111/0 0/0 "GET /ws/site/V3L235F/d88r3567pssllp/ HTTP/1.1"
```

But when instead of `ip_address:port` there's a `-:port`, for example:

```
May 21 08:25:56 ha haproxy[5089]: -:89012 [21/May/2021:08:25:56.055] www-https~ wss/wssnode website.domain.com 1/1/1/1/111 111 111 - - ---- 11111/11111/11111/111/0 0/0 "GET /ws/site/V3L235F/d88r3567pssllp/ HTTP/1.1"
```

I have an error:

> Provided Grok expressions do not match field value: May 21 08:25:56 ha
> haproxy[5089]: -:89012 [21/May/2021:08:25:56.055] www-https~
> wss/wssnode website.domain.com 1/1/1/1/111 111 111 - - ----
> 11111/11111/11111/111/0 0/0 "GET /ws/site/V3L235F/d88r3567pssllp/
> HTTP/1.1

Here's my [/usr/share/filebeat/module/haproxy/log/pipline.json](https://gist.github.com/maarsaks/0d9b094da9e5747050be03184a031b16)

I was trying to resolve this by adding a new pattern to `grok` with `message` field and by editing `grok` pattern with `source.address` field without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at your pipeline grok patterns.
Taking cue from that, I modified the IP section a bit.

```
(%{IP:source.address}|-):%{NUMBER:port}
```

You can use something like this, I have given test names to the variables. You can changes accordingly.

---

The output for the following is as follows:

Example 1 => `12.34.56.78:89012`

```
{
  "source": [
    [
      "12.34.56.78"
    ]
  ],
  "port": [
    [
      "89012"
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

Example 2 => `-:89012`

```
{
  "source": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "port": [
    [
      "89012"
    ]
  ]
}
```